# How can I execute a command over a distance of more than 100 blocks?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm using MC Bedrock (On Windows 10), and I want to execute a command at `5000 ~ 5000` using a command block placed at `0 ~ 0`. I know this is not possible (at least not without using some other method than mine) because command blocks have a limit of 100 blocks' distance in which their command is able to run. I have attempted to circumvent this with a very long loop of /execute commands, like this: `/execute @s 100 ~ 100 execute @s 200 ~ 200 execute @s 300 ~ 300` and so on. This has not worked. How can I execute a command over a distance of more than 100 blocks?

Comment: Don't use command blocks, use functions instead

Comment: Please can you expand?

Comment: Are you saying that functions execute over the whole world?

Comment: Yep, functions don't care which chucks are loaded, whereas command blocks do. Some caveats though, nothing will happen in a chunk of it's not loaded, but the function will still run.

Comment: Ok thanks, do you know if there's any way to load a chunk remotely?

Answer (score -1):

Use things such as dx, dy, and dz they will always go the distance you set them to based in the diameter created by distance x to distance y and distance z, and distance y to distance x and distance z, and distance z to distance x and distance y, the distance being distance from the command block, so often times, the range will be bigger than you want it, which is where math comes into play, which there is a question somewhere on this site with a answer explaining it if you want more details, or just ask me.

Comment: That or just give a specific set of coordinates, e.g. ```execute @s <x y z> execute @s <x y z> execute @s <x y z>``` there's ways to bend the rules of a command block, it's the most powerful tool in minecraft

Comment: (The only tool to use commands with really, besides chat) but it can store commands till ready to be used